# How to update component if data disappears after page reloads?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

What I want:

When the page loads, I get data fetched from DB. Then, cause I join the presence channel('chat'), I would like to see  the new user name to be display on the page, below all previously fetched users.

What I get:

I get a warning  [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Then
when I reload the page I see data from DB(users fetched), then it disappears and immediately last data (`user.name`) shows up. The question is how to prevent this from happening?

**Component.vue**

```
  <tr v-for="user in users"> 
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.ip}}</td>
  </tr>     

<script>
name:'Online',
     data() {
        return {
            users:[],  
            user: ''    
       }    
   },   

 mounted() {
        window.Echo.channel('channelName')
            .listen('eventIp', (e) => {
                this.user = e;    
            });
          window.Echo.join('chat')
            .here(users => (this.users = users))
            .joining(user => (this.users.push(user)))
            .leaving(user => (this.users = this.users.filter(u => (u.id 
                                                !==user.id)))
        );    
    this.fetchData()
   },

methods: {
     fetchData(){
              axios
                .get('api/person')
                .then(response => (this.users= response.data))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
     },
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you may need to edit the question to clarify precisely what the current behaviour is and what you would like it to be. It really isn't clear how the two states that occur post-reload relate to the state pre-reload or which of those states you regard as incorrect. The confusion is exacerbated because you use `user.name` to refer to two different things. Incidentally I would highly recommend not using `v-html` unless you really have to, use `{{ user.name }}` instead if you possibly can.

Comment: @skirtle I updated a question.